# Android Studio hangs on memory overuse while using profiler allocations records to find memory leaks in my app , what to do?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory-management, memory-profiling

Its quite frustrating while tool hangs on memory usage while trying to fix same issue in app I am developing using it. I tried increase of memory but not anough obviously, I hav e just 8 GB and using apple M1 Macbook, this machine runs miraculously quick otherwise, first time I have any issue with speed. Using latest Arctic Fox Patch 2, Any ideas ?

When I do record alocation I have to kill Android Studio when I capture heap it sometimes stays usable but gives warnings...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In settings I already had highest possible memory options so I went to edit studio.vmoptions in bin of android studio package and changed first two options to:

-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m

It's just blind guess this numbers basically I duplicated what was already there but works.